# How to use SpinButton in a condition

Tags: vba, userform

I have a spin button and a two list boxes. i have set the min and max of spin button. I already have a button which moves data from list box1 to listbox2.But i want to set a limit for moving the data based on spin button.
example:
  if value in spin button is 2, then only 2 items can be added to listbox2

note:i have linked the spin button to a textbox

Comment: How are you moving the data from LB1 to LB2?

Comment: i am selecting each item and adding it to listbox2 using for loop

Comment: jctr = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Text)  this will give me the value set in textbox. if want to check for a condition if data entered in listbox2>jctr error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable and then every time you move an item, increment the value of the variable by 1. So next time when you click the button to move the item, simply compare the value of the variable with the `SpinButton's` Value. For example (Untested)

```
Dim nMoved As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If nMoved < (VAL(TextBox1.Text) + 1)
        '
        '~~> Code to move items from LB1 to LB2
        '

        nMoved = nMoved + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "Max items that can be moved from LB1 to LB2 reached."
    End If
End Sub
```

**FollowUp from Comments**

You need to use `.ListCount` in your case only if you are matching the items count in the LB against the TB. What I understood from your post is a user shouldn't be able to move more items into the LB than what is specified in the TB. Anyways, it seems that your query is sorted.

Regarding your 2nd comment.

You need to loop through the LB items using the code below and then exit the loop if the `counter` is equal to the TB value. For example

```
For i = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
    If i = (Val(TextBox1.Text) - 1) Then Exit For
        '
        '~~> Code to move items from LB1 to LB2
        '
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you i got it by using Dim jctr As Integer
    jctr = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Value)
If jctr = ListBox2.ListCount Then
 MsgBox "exceeding team limit"
 Else  'code for moving

Comment: i have one more issue. i have set spin value as 2. if i want to move all the data from list1 to list2. it should copy only first 2, because spinvalue=2 how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all.. finally i got the answer

```
Dim ct As Integer
Dim ictr As Long
Dim jctr As Integer
jctr = CInt(Me.TextBox1.Value)
If jctr = ListBox2.ListCount Then
   MsgBox "Maximum limit has been reached. You cannot add more players"
    Exit Sub
End If
  For ictr = jctr To 1 Step -1
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(ictr)
Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem ictr
Next ictr
```

Comment: This selects number of item based on input in spin value. but if there is already item present in the listbox2 then the above code adds item to it. ex: if spin value is 3 and there's already a item in the box2, add all button adds 3 items to box2. which is an error because total items in box2 should be 3 instead there will be 4. how can i debug this??